# A question about sendmail macros and tls

Tags: ssl, sendmail

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19120-01/open.solaris/819-1634/fvbqm/index.html

Here i read some sendmail macros must be edited on mc file
to work
I want tls use version 1 and strong cipher
How to put correct macro?

This

```
D{tls_version}TLSv1
D${cipher}DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA
```

Or this?

```
define(`confTLS_VERSION', `TLSv1')dnl
define(`confCIPHER', `DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA')dnl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version (`D...`) is a "raw" `sendmail.cf` content.
The second version (`define(...)`) is recommended `sendmail.mc` content to generate the above "raw" version in `sendmail.cf`.

You should use the second set of lines in your `sendmail.mc`.